# LC3 simulator checks if a register is greater than 0

Tags: lc3

How do I check if a register is greater than 0? 
For example: I want to check if R2 is greater than 0

This is what I did: 
ADD R2, R2, #0

But this doesn't check if R2 is greater than 0, it seems like it sets R2's value to 0

Answer (score 0):

To check if a register is greater than zero is a two step process.

First you will need to set the condition code register and then you will use the BR instruction to branch on a condition.

```
ADD R2, R2, 0          ; Store R2 in R2, this has no effect other than setting CC register.
BRNZ LESS_THAN_OR_ZERO ; Branch if R2 is <= 0, based on the CC register set in last instruction
[statements here]      ; if we are here then R2 > 0
BR DONE                ; optional if we don't want to execute the next section of code. unconditional branch to done
LESS_THAN_OR_ZERO
[more statements here] ; if we are here then R2 <= 0
DONE
[more statements here]
```

More about the CC register, it is updated with N, Z, or P based on the last instruction that writes to a register that means LD, LEA, LDI, LDR, ADD, AND, and NOT will update the CC register automatically.

Check out the ISA documentation for the BR instruction.